# Android 2.1: H.264 video is not playing through RTSP, only audio

Tags: video, streaming, android, h.264

I'm using [Wowza Media Server](http://www.wowzamedia.com/) for video streaming to mobile devices and have troubles with RTSP-streaming to Android 2.1. I tried their [test `.mov` file](http://www.wowzamedia.com/demos/mobile.html) and it works. But when I try to play my own `.mp4` files, I get only the audio, but no picture.

Here are the ffmpeg settings I used to encode files:

```
-r 12 -s 176x144 -f mp4 -acodec libfaac -ab 24k -ar 48000 -vcodec libx264 -level 30 -b 56k
-flags +loop+mv4 -cmp 256 -partitions +parti4x4+parti8x8+partp4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8
-me_method hex -subq 7 -trellis 1 -refs 1 -bf 0 -flags2 +mixed_refs-wpred-dct8x8 -coder 0
-wpredp 0 -me_range 16 -g 250 -keyint_min 25 -sc_threshold 40 -i_qfactor 0.71
-qmin 10 -qmax 51 -qdiff 4 -maxrate 10M -bufsize 10M -threads 0
```

After encoding I did `qt-faststart video.mp4` and `MP4Box -hint video.mp4`
Could you please tell me what am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem by using [EncodeHD](http://dcunningham.net/media-tools/encodehd/). It knows how to prepare video for different kinds of devices, and in the logs I have found the necessary command-line to use with ffmpeg:

```
-vcodec libx264 -coder 0 -flags +loop -cmp +chroma -partitions +parti4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8 -rc_eq 'blurCplx^(1-qComp)' -me_method hex -subq 6 -me_range 16 -g 250 -keyint_min 25 -sc_threshold 40 -i_qfactor 0.71 -b_strategy 1 -qcomp 0.6 -qmin 10 -qmax 51 -qdiff 4 -directpred 1 -flags2 +fastpskip -threads 0  -level 30 -b 1012k -minrate 1012k -maxrate 1012k -bufsize 1012k -s 480x270 -r 30 -acodec aac -strict experimental -ac 2 -ar 44100 -ab 96k
```

Sorry for answering my own question. I hope that helps someone.